# Purpose of xml inside a dll

Tags: xml, dll

I'm working on a project which has a dll as target. The build process includes a prebuild directive which creates a header file out of a xml file which then is included via External Dependencies.

Next thing is, once you loaded this library you are able to access this xml file from another library and create lets say a nodemap out of its content ["everything in an XML document is a node"](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes.asp).

So my question is, why would somebody use this kind of mechanism? Couldn't it be done somehow 
easier? What kind of information would you put inside this xml?

The purpose of the dll in general is to access an external device. Inside the xml are some entries about the access parameters and protocol name.

I'm using c++ and VS 2010.

EDIT: I try to provide some simple example code (although its not working):

```
 //example.xml:
 <Int Name ="TransportLayerVersionNumber NameSpace="Custom">
   <Length>4</Length>
   <Port>TLPort</Port>
    <Sign>Unsigned</Sign>
    <Endianess>LittleEndian</Endianess>
 </Int>

 // example.cpp
 Node myNode = GetNode(TransportLayerVersionNumber);
 myNode.GetEndianess();
```

Comment: Please give more detail of the technologies you are working with (Language, IDE?)...

Comment: @DrewR using c++ in VS 2010

Comment: It's kind of hard to know the specifics in your case, so tell us more. Are there any documentation for this dll ? What's in the xml file ? Why are you using this dll ? Maybe it's simple configuration parameters, maybe it creates a mapping telling you how to transform one kind of data to another kind of data, maybe the xml file is used in another project as an interface description to 3. party tools

Comment: @nos the purpose of the dll is to access an external device. Inside the xml are some entries about the access parameters and protocol name

Comment: I am speculating but it is possible that an accessor class is being generated based on the XML's schema so that you might interact with it. Really cannot say more without looking at the XML / some code.

Comment: @fischblog then perhaps either the xml file is generated so you can use it to e.g. generate docs for the device, access it via just manipulating xml instead of writing C++ code. Perhaps there's many types of devices, in in which case you can interact with it by just manipulating an XML structure of each in a general way. Or the .dll is generated out of a xml file describing the device, allowing the authors to just code a general parser that produces C++ code, instead of writing specific C++ code for the particular device.